# I’m looking for “My own Wikipedia”

Tags: web-apps, software-development, iphone-app, wiki, macbook

Hello internet friends,

I’m really looking for a software or an app (specifically for iPhone) even maybe a website of some sort to create my own Wikipedia for my self. I love to write Game designs for my free time and sometimes for my friends games.
So I always looking for some kind of place to write down all my ideas, but I’m tired to use google docs for this task because I want something really organized in one place maybe in one folder with maybe a side menu where I can see all of my previous concepts/entry/values that I created

And if I wrote in a new page the same title page name of my previous value then it will automatically connect between the 2, that if someone from out side will read my “Wikipedia” and he will stumble across a “term” that have a specific page in my Wikipedia the he would redirected to that page for more information in a click. And if he clicks exit or back he will return to the previous page.
Some kind of “Glossary“

Mandy I want that if something like this exists then it will cross platformed because I mainly write on my phone.
Most importantly... it should be free for privet usage. But is it’s not possible then ok.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of such tools. Just take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software or at [this structured comparison of various Wikis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software). I personally use *TiddlyWiki* for my purposes, but many other tools will do.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a personal wiki, but after trying different wiki software. I ended up using Notion ([www.notion.so](http://www.notion.so))

Comment: Adding a link is nice convenience to readers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/59215)

Comment: @Tom The software suggested includes a wiki so it is an answer. It would be a better answer with more description.